# Zeroing out one element of a correlation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $R$ be a correlation matrix.  Is there some $T$ such that 
$$
TRT' = Z^{(ij)},
$$
for $i \neq j$, where the $(m,n)$th element of $Z^{(ij)}$ is given by
$$
  Z_{mn}^{(ij)} = \begin{cases}
            0 & \quad \text{if} \quad m = i, n = j \\
            0 & \quad \text{if} \quad m = j, n = i \\
            R_{mn} & \quad \text{otherwise},
           \end{cases}
$$
Therefore matrix $Z^{(ij)}$ has a $0$ in the $(i, j)$th position (and $(j, i)$th position)?  That is, can we pre- and post-multiply $R$ by some matrix to zero out a specific off-diagonal element?

Comment: Certainly this can be done, because there is an orthogonal matrix $T$ that will make ALL of the off-diagonal elements $0$.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix $\begin{bmatrix} Z_{ii} & Z_{ij} \\  Z_{ji} &  Z_{jj} \end{bmatrix}$ is itself a correlation matrix, and so can be diagonalized by a $2\times 2$ orthogonal matrix, which will be of the form $\begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\  \sin\theta &  \cos\theta \end{bmatrix}$.

So let $T_{ii} = T_{jj} = \cos\theta$, $T_{ij}=-T_{ji}=\sin\theta$, $T_{kk} = 1$ for $i\ne k\ne j$, and $T_{k\ell}=0$ for all other pairs $k,\ell$ of indices.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  Will this preserve all of the other elements of the original matrix?  That is, will the diagonal elements remain 1 and non-diagonals (besides _i,j_ and _j,i_) be preserved?